# transform a numpy array of dimensions nx1 into a numpy array of dimensions nx10

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array, `A` of size `nx1` where each value is a number between 0 and 9.

I would like to create a new array, `B` of size `nx10` such that in `B[i]` we store a numpy array that contains zeros and a 1 in position `A[i]`.

For example:

```
A array
[[9]
 [2]
 [4]
 [1]
 [8]]

B array
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this with numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new empty array using `numpy.zeros`, its size is going to be (`arr.size`, `arr.max()`), now fill the items on those positions using multi-dimensional indexing:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[9], [2], [4], [1], [8]])
>>> arr_ = np.zeros((arr.size, arr.max()))
>>> arr_[np.arange(arr.size), arr[:,0]-1] = 1
>>> arr_
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it:

```
A = [[9],[2],[4],[1],[8]]
B = [[1 if i == j[0] else 0 for i in range(10)] for j in A]
```

This is a list-based approach; you can simply use np.asarray on B to get the numpy matrix, or create a 10x10 matrix of zeros in numpy and fill 1s in the positions dictated by the A array.

The latter generalises to the case where A's elements might have more than one item.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, assuming an NP Nx1 array of X:

```
max_val = max(X)
length_arr = len(X)
new_arr = np.zeros((max_val,length_arr))
```

This will create the array of the right size that you want.

```
for i in range(len(X)):
    new_arr[i][X[i]-1]=1
```

Should then assign the correct values in place?

Works fine in my test case.